# Change excel formula syntax using indirect function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I want to change formula syntax basis user selection in excel drop down. For example: replace Small with Large in `=Small(F3:F16,1)`, if user selects Large from drop down given.

I tried `="="&INDIRECT("H2")&"(F5:F16,1)"` where `H2` is the drop down containing Small and Large. but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of actually using the text itself as a function, I would just use an `IF` statement, i.e. something like:

```
= IF(H2="Large",LARGE(F5:F16,1),SMALL(F3:F16,1))
```

Comment: Hey Peter, Thank you for quick help. yes this is definitely the solution, however i was trying to use Indirect specifically :)

Comment: @DeepakVed `INDIRECT` is dangerous and should always be avoided if possible. There are only a few cases where it actually is needed.

Comment: Oh Ok. IMHO i believe that Indirect is not a volatile function. Is it?

Comment: @DeepakVed `INDIRECT` and `OFFSET` (similar to `INDIRECT`) are both volatile.

Comment: @DeepakVed - `INDIRECT` is a volatile function and is used to convert text string into a range and not what your thinking of.

Comment: I stand corrected. Thank you for your help Peter and Mrig :)

Answer (score 1):

Indirect can only reference range, and it cannot change formula part. you should use If/choose statement instead.

```
=IF(H2="Small",SMALL(F3:F16,1),LARGE(F3:F16,1))
```

Comment: Hey Kresimir,, Thank you for quick response. I might end up using If function only :)

Comment: You're welcome. please mark one of the answers as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use excel functions which use numbers to refer to functions like `AGGREGATE` or `SUBTOTAL`, e.g.

`=AGGREGATE(IF(H2="LARGE",4,5),4,F3:F16)`